# Sorting names of files in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, file-io

I'm writing a script in Perl that I want to run on all the `.csv` files in a given directory. The names of the files are of the type: `CCCC0.csv, CCCC1.csv, ..., CCCC198.csv`. However, I want Perl to first run the script on file `CCCC0.csv`, than on `CCCC1.csv` etc...So, basically, according to the increasing value of the number at the end of the file name. 
If I write:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $file;
my @files = <*.csv>;
my @orderedfiles = sort @files;
for $file (@orderedfiles) {

... do stuff

}
```

it first runs on `CCCC100.csv` rather than `CCCC11.csv` while if i write

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $file;
my @files = <*.csv>;
my @orderedfiles = sort { substr($a, 4) <=> substr($b, 4)  } @files;
for $file (@orderedfiles) {

... do stuff

}
```

it gives me an error telling me that I'm not ordering a numeric (I assume that he doesn't understand that it's a number after the 4 characters rather than another character.)
I have looked at the countless questions on Stackoverflow or perlmonks that deal with sorting but i haven't been able to find an answer to my question.

EDIT: I'm using a windows machine.

Comment: If you're using a Unix shell,I wouldn't include this logic into the script and simply use `ls *.csv | xargs -d '\n'  yourscriptname` or similar.

Comment: Sorry, should have added that I'm using a Windows machine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there... the '.CSV' is still there. You'd be better served using regex to read just numeric characters.

```
my @sorted = sort { ($a =~ /(\d+)/)[0] <=> ($b =~ /(\d+)/)[0] } @files;
```

There is an idiom called the [Schwartzian Transform](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Schwartzian_transform) that can also do this, though it takes a CS major to understand :D

```
my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }             # return the sorted file names
                                          #
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } # sort on the numeric portion
                                          #
             map  { [$_, /(\d+)/] }       # wrap the file names in a temporary 
             @files;                      #   array with their numeric portions.

                                          # ^^ read from bottom to top ^^
```

Comment: Thank you: after reading the above comment I was trying to trim the last 4 characters using `substr($a, 4, -4)` but I couldn't make it work (surprisingly, it would work if I input the array manually, to run a test in Perl but it WOULDN'T work on the actual data files...)... However, your code did the job: thanks!

Comment: Odd... It works fine for me using subst as you describe, like so `@order = sort { substr($a,4,-4) <=> substr($b,4,-4) } @files;` and in fact, this might be preferable. It only looks at the substring in that indexed location (4, -4) so it would protect against edge cases like numbers in the first 4 characters of your filename.

Answer (score 3):

You could give [Sort::Key::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural) a spin.  From the synopsis:

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);

my @data = qw(foo1 foo23 foo6 bar12 bar1
              foo bar2 bar-45 foomatic b-a-r-45);

my @sorted = natsort @data;

print "@sorted\n";
# prints:
#   b-a-r-45 bar1 bar2 bar12 bar-45 foo foo1 foo6 foo23 foomatic
```

Comment: Thanks Jim: this is actually very powerful and is probably the closest to a general answer to my question! I will read the documentation to get a better idea of what it does!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the substr($a, 4) is returning "100.csv" in your example, so that you need to trim the .csv suffix off it still.